# Adding an json-object to the the angular-model?

Tags: angularjs

I'm testing out angular for the first time. In javascript I have a json-object. How do I make it available to use in my angular template?

Comment: Angular use regular objects. Assigning it to a scope property will work out of the box. You should have a look at AngularJS [Tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and [Developer Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your json-object needs to be in the scope of a controller:

```
$scope.obj = /* some data */
```

And inside the HTML, simply refer to it as `obj`. For example to iterate over it:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular comes with a `angular.fromJson(jsonData)` method that you can use to transform your `JSON`data into a JavaScript object.

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.fromJson

Then you just need to expose it on a scope like:

```
$scope.myData = angular.fromJson(jsonData);
```

Now you are free to use it in your templates:

```
<div>{{myData.someProperty}}</div>
```